# Magento 2: What is difference between Cache Clean & Cache Refresh?

Tags: magento2, cache, block-cache

What is difference between cache refresh (when we select something and click refresh) and Cache clean? [image]

Answer (score 1):

## Cache Flush

Flushing a cache type purges the cache storage, which might affect other processes applications that are using the same storage.

## Cache Refresh

Cleaning a cache type deletes and regenerate all items from enabled Magento cache types only. In other words, this option does not affect other processes or applications because it cleans only the cache that Magento uses.

**Disabled cache types are not cleaned.**

**Reference:** [DevDocs Clean and flush cache types](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html#config-cli-subcommands-cache-clean)

Comment: not sure that this is the answer because the author doesn't ask about the difference between **cleaning cache** and **flushing cache**

Answer (score 1):

**Cache clean**:

- Remove magento enabled cache and regenerate when page load

**Cache Refresh**:

- Remove magento enabled cache and regenerate all enabled cache again

**Fluch Cache storage**:

- Remove all magento as well as third-party cache

Comment: What I don't understand: why would one share the cache with another application/instance? Any examples regardikng third-party? Who or what els is using the cache? Is it the cache in var/cache?

Answer (score 0):

no the is no difference. Basically orange button "Flush Magento Cache" does absolutely the same as if you select all cache types and refresh them.

The difference only exists between **Flush cache storage** and **Flush Magento Cache**

UPD #1:
Take a look at awesome [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZvnBTK8uUM) from John Hughes about caching in Magento 2 I believe after that things become more clear for you.

Answer (score -1):

**php bin/magento cache:clean**

> Cleaning a cache type deletes all items from enabled Magento cache
>   types only. In other words, this option does not affect other
>   processes or applications because it cleans only the cache that
>   Magento uses.
>
> Disabled cache types are not cleaned.

**php bin/magento cache:flush**

> Flushing a cache type purges the cache storage, which might affect
>   other processes applications that are using the same storage.